# using list.append() replaces list instead of adding new value

Tags: python, list, append

I am using the simple code block

```
while True:
    trend = list()
    trend.append(priceRPX())
    print trend
    sleep(1)
```

however after running once it doesn't keep adding new additions to the list and instead just replaces the first.

Comment: move `trend = list()` outside of `while loop`.

Comment: Your code says _"On repeat forever, create an empty list and append something onto it, display the list, then pause."_ --- Can you see why you never get more than 1 element in your list?

Comment: @byxor I understand, should I delete this question?

Comment: @Sumtinlazy Only delete it if you think nobody else will benefit from it. If it's unsatisfactory, moderators will likely close the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialized variable `trend` outside of loop:

```
trend = list()
while True:
   trend.append(priceRPX())
   print trend
   sleep(1)
```